# Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, postman

Necesito obtener por medio del id del guest_id su informacion, pero al poner el parametro en postman

```
localhost:80/isac/apis/users.php?guest_id=3
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\isac\apis\users.php** on line **21** 
>   
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\isac\apis\users.php** on line **22** 
>   
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\isac\apis\users.php** on line **23** 
>   
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\isac\apis\users.php** on line **24** 
>   
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\isac\apis\users.php** on line **25** 
>   
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\isac\apis\users.php** on line **26** 
>   
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\isac\apis\users.php** on line **27** 
>   {"status":0,"user":{"guest_id":null,"guest_name":null,"guest_lastName":null,"guest_phoneNumber":null,"guest_email":null,"guest_status":null,"guest_date":null}}

```
<?php
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
      require_once('../apis/connection.php');

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
    {
      if(isset($_GET['guest_id']))
      {
        $id_user=$_GET["guest_id"];    
         $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();

        $query = 'SELECT guest_id, guest_name, guest_lastName,
        guest_phoneNumber,guest_email,guest_status,guest_date
         FROM guests WHERE guest_id = ?';
        $result=$connection->executeQuery($query, array($id_user));

        if ($result > 0 )
        {
          $user = json_encode(array(
                          'guest_id' => $result[0][0],
                          'guest_name' => $result[0][1],
                          'guest_lastName' => $result[0][2],
                          'guest_phoneNumber' => $result[0][3],
                          'guest_email' => $result[0][4],
                          'guest_status' => $result[0][5],
                          'guest_date' => $result[0][6]
                        ));
          echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 0,
            'user' => json_decode($user)
            ));
        }//if
        else
        {
          echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 1,
            'errorMessage' => 'user not found'
            ));
        }//else
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: ¿por qué haces esto?: `$result[0][0]` pareciera que tratas de acceder a un elemento de un array dentro de otro arraty, trata de agregar mas detalles al respecto

Comment: Anteriormente ya habia hecho apis de esta manera y habia obtenido en ocasiones el mismo error, pero ahora no se soluciona.

Comment: Si quieres suprimir ese aviso solo tienes que agregar @ a la variable en la linea 22 . ese error es por que no se octiene  un valor .

Comment: Dado que utilizas una clase propia `MySqlServerConnection` que no sabemos que hace y tampoco sabemos que devuelve el metodo `executeQuery` poco te podemos ayudar. Solo decir que el Undefined offset se presenta cuando intentas acceder a un elemento del array que no existe.

Comment: El problema viene del método `executeQuery()` de tu clase `MySqlServerConnection` como indica correctamente @Xerif . Para poder ayudarte debemos conocer su implementación (edita tu pregunta [pulsando aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/283021/edit) para agregar el código). PD: No es necesario que uses `json_encode` en un dato de PHP para luego asignarlo usando `json_decode`.